# Don't format Grand Totals rows / columns

Tags: excel, vba

I've come up with the below VBA which aims to add conditional formatting to a pivot table even when row and column items are changed. There are grand total rows for the columns and rows which i'm trying to exclude from this conditional formatting using the rannge.resize function.

Could anyone explain why it isnt working please? its still including the grand total rows and columns in the conditional formatting.

```
Sub CondFormat()
Dim rg As Range
Dim cs As ColorScale
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).DataBodyRange
Rng.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count - 1, Rng.Columns.Count - 1).Select
Rng.FormatConditions.Delete
'colour scale will have three colours
Set cs = Rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3)
With cs
    'the first colour is green
    With .ColorScaleCriteria(1)
        .FormatColor.Color = RGB(70, 255, 90)
        .Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
        .Value = 10
    End With
    'the second colour is white set at value 18
    With .ColorScaleCriteria(2)
        .FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
        .Value = 80
    End With
    'the third colour is red
    With .ColorScaleCriteria(3)
        .FormatColor.Color = RGB(200, 130, 120)
        .Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
        .Value = 10
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try replacing `Set cs = Rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3)` with `Set cs = Rng.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count - 1, Rng.Columns.Count - 1).FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3)`. You do `Set Rng = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).DataBodyRange` so `Rng` is binded always to full databodyrange, even if you resize it (you don't save the resizing into a new range object)

Comment: Thats worked perfectly, thanks for the code and the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

`Set cs = Rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3)` with

```
Set cs = Rng.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count - 1, Rng.Columns.Count - 1).FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3).
```

You do `Set Rng = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).DataBodyRange` so `Rng` **is binded always to full databodyrange**, even if you resize it (you don't save the resizing into a new range object)